# Following a Lynda.com c++ tutorial and having problems setting up paths on Eclipse (OSX 10.9.3)

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, gcc, path

I am currently learning C++ using Lynda.com tutorials, I am a complete beginner and am following the tutorials on how to set up Eclipse on my Mac.
When I initially run the version-test.cpp program provided, it runs fine with the expected output (GCC version 4.2.1)

The tutorial requires my Mac to be running GCC version 4.7.0 or above and it explains how to upgrade GCC. The tutorial instructs me to save the updated GCC files within my home directory within the folder hpc-gcc and then follows on to explain the method to set my PATHs to find this folder.

Now when I run the version-test.cpp program it fails with the following error

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmpc.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/gary/hpc-gcc/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/4.9.0/cc1plus

Reason: image not found

So from this message I can see that the system cannot find the required files within /usr/local/lib.

I am able to copy the files from hpc-gcc/bin to /usr/local/lib and have the program compile and run correctly but I am hoping to find out why Eclipse cannot read the required files directly from ~/hpc-gcc/bin

I have spent the last 2 hours searching forums and search engines for the answer but I am no further forward. I realise I can simply have the GCC files within /usr/local/lib and it will work but I want to understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved.

You need to go into the properties of the Working folder (if you are following the lynda.com program you will understand the working folder) and under C/C++ Build -> Environment menu (Where we added in the `LIBRARY_PATH`, `PATH`, AND `CPATH` variables) and add in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` with a value of `${HOME}/hpc-gcc/lib`.

Remember the C/C++ Build "menus" are for build and debug, so the project is not able to find the library for the building process.

And you will be good to go.